# Capturar la validación del form request en laravel y pasarlos a la vista vue

Tags: ajax, laravel, json, laravel-5, vue.js

¿Como puedo capturar el resultado del form validation del controlador y mostrarlo en la vista vue?

Tengo el método Store en el controlador CategoryController que se encarga de validar e ingresar los datos a la db, necesito que pasar a la vista el resultado de la validación, la cual es si se ingresaron caracteres, números o espacios en blanco, para que de esta forma pueda después pasar los datos a la tabla mediante Axios.

¿Alguna idea?, estoy ocupando Laravel 5.6 y Vuejs 2

Comment: Deberá añadir el código de como está haciendo actualmente el proceso.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, muchas gracias por tu consejo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes mejorar la pregunta y aportar mas elementos para dar respuestas en concreto y no divagar. Por lo que pude entender quieres enviar alertas de validaciones de la controller a la vista; de esta forma realizo mis validaciones y envió errores a la vista:

```
public function locked_check(Request $request){

    $email = Auth::user()->name;

    if(LockSession::isLocked() && Auth::attempt([
            'name' => $email,
            'password' => $request->get('password')
        ]))
    {
        $to = LockSession::unlock();

        return redirect($to);

    } elseif(LockSession::isLocked()){

        return redirect()->route('locked')->with('errors', collect(['password' => 'Sus credenciales son incorrectas']));

    }
    return redirect()->route('locked');
}

public function locked(Request $request){
        //Solo puede acceder a esta página se se blokea primero
        if(!LockSession::isLocked()){
            return back();
        }
        return view('users.bloqueo');
    }
```

Código en la vista:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('locked_check') }}">
                                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                            <label class="block clearfix">
                                               <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                                   <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Contrase&ntilde;a" required autofocus/>
                                                   <i class="ace-icon fa fa-lock"></i>
                                               </span>

                                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                                    <span class="help-block">
                                                        <strong>{{ $errors->get('password') }}</strong>
                                                    </span>
                                                @endif
                                            </label>

                                        </div>

                                        <div class="space"></div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                                    Acceder
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                              </form>
```

Espero te sirva!

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, yo tenía algo parecido a lo que muestras, el problema era pasar eso mismo pero a las vistas hechas en vuejs.

Answer (score 0):

se lo pasa a vue de esta forma y ya esta:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    ministries: {!! json_encode($variable) !!}
  },
});
```

donde `$variable` es una variable que pasas desde tu controller